# asp.net file input post on another page (cross page scripting file upload using ajax)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

**file.aspx**

```
<form action="data/exec.aspx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" required="required" id="image"/>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

**exec.aspx**

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["image"];
if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0 )
{
    try
    {
        string fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("../images/" + fname)));
        Response.Write("done " + fname);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

When I submit the form, nothing happens and file is null. I also tried `asp:file` upload but had the same problem.

Similar code worked on php example on exec.php page `$_FILES["image"]["name"]` it posts image and saves, but it doesn't work in ASP.NET cross page post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="doc" id="doc" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
<script>
    $("form#form1").submit(function () {

        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'recive.aspx',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data)
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

i am using jquery and ajax to post data from another form

**recive.aspx**

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["doc"];
        if(file!=null)
        {
            string fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(fname)));
            Response.Write("done " + fname);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("file empty");
        }
```